# Job failed to load: uninitialized constant with Delayed Job and Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

I'm trying to utilize Delayed Job in my Rails 3 app, but keep hitting a snag. The jobs keep failing with the error: `Job failed to load: uninitialized constant CrawlJob.`

I found a couple of other SO threads and followed advice there to no avail. Here is the relevant code.

**Application.rb**

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'
```

...

```
module Decurate
  class Application < Rails::Application
```

...

```
    config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
    config.autoload_paths += Dir["#{config.root}/lib/**/"]
```

...

```
  end
end
```

**/lib/crawl_job.rb**

```
class CrawlJob < Struct.new(:merchant_id,:ec2,:s3)
  def perform
```

...

```
  end
end
```

**/lib/tasks/cron.rake**

```
  merchants = Store.all.collect{ |store| store[:merchant_id] }
  merchants.each do |merchant_id|
    queue.push merchant_id
  end
  merchants.each do |merchant_id|
    Delayed::Job.enqueue CrawlJob.new(merchant_id,@ec2,@s3)
  end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry everyone, it seems that I simply forgot to restart my worker processes as I was messing with the autoload_paths. For reference, the above arrangement should work. Just remember to start up a new worker with `rake jobs:work`!